# Unable to locate package gcc-objc

Tags: software-installation, objective-c

Trying to install compiler for objective c.
Although net connection is working well.

```
pallavi@pallavi-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-objc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-objc
pallavi@pallavi-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Did you run apt-get update first? What Ubuntu release are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The package name is `gobjc` – the *GNU Objective-C compiler*, therefore

```
sudo apt-get install gobjc
```

or the *GNU Objective-C++ compiler*

```
sudo apt-get install gobjc++
```